# How to draw map from pixel array

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to load a map from a image, I get the hex codes for every pixel on my image, which is put into map[]. The world[] will store 1 or 0 or whatever number for number of sprite on the spritesheet. If the color is #8aff00 then it will store 0 for grass. The map is 16 by 16 pixels, which is my world size. When I try to make the world array, the for statement is working right, there is no errors. I know I have all the data, but this part of my function is not working, it just stops after these for statements:

```
    function createWorld() {
       for (var y=0; y < worldHeight; y++) {
           for (var x=0; x < worldWidth; x++) {
             if (map[pl] == '#8aff00') world[x][y] = 0;
             if (map[pl] == '#000000') world[x][y] = 1;
             pl+=4;
          }
       }
       alert('about to draw');
       draw();

   }
```

The alert never gets called. When I displayed the x and y, it went '0,0' to '1,0' then back to '0,0' for the value x and y. The pl is for which number of the array I want. When I put another for statement to handle that it messed up more. Is there something wrong with the code, if you need more of the code just let me know.

Comment: Where did you define `worldHeight`, `worldWidth`, `world` and `pl`??

Comment: You could add command `console.log(x, y, pl, map[pl], worldHeight, worldWidth);` at the end of the inner loop and post the output from Development tools console (F12 in most browsers) here for more info...

Comment: I know, I'm programming on textastic on my ipad.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to build code which is working.

Now it's Your turn to implement it as You need.

```
worldHeight = 16;
worldWidth = 16;
world = {};
map = ['#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000','#8aff00','#000000']
pl = 0

function draw(){
    console.log(world);
}

function createWorld() {
       for (var y=0; y < worldHeight; y++) {
           for (var x=0; x < worldWidth; x++) {
             if (map[pl] == '#8aff00')
                 world[x] = 0;
                 world[x][y] = 0;
             if (map[pl] == '#000000')
                 world[x] = 0;
                 world[x][y] = 1;
             pl+=4;
          }
       }
       alert('about to draw');
       draw();

}

createWorld();
```

Cheers.

Comment: When I go to createWorld, world[x][y] is returning undefined.

Comment: Not sure if I had to tag you or not: @KamilW

Comment: @Loudermilk I wish I could help You with Your code. `world[x][y]` is global variable. Shouldn't be undefined. Maybe You just need to add `var` before (line 3). Feel free to use `console.log(world)` in many places of Your code to see, when and where `world` is initialized or use Javascript debugger. Maybe You didn't properly initialized `world` in Your code?

Comment: In my draw method world is returning something like: "0,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,0,,,0,,0,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,0"

Comment: Keep forgetting to tag you @KamilW

Comment: @Loudermilk It looks like there is many empty elements. I have another idea. Why not initializing a dictionary? Like this:
`var world = new Array(16);
var x = [-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1];
for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    world[i] = x;
  }
console.log(world);`  or You may see it in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X3Ed8/)
This way You may avoid getting empty element in array. Just use `if(world > -1)` or You may use function `isNaN( )` which answers if element is a number or not. Cheers.